# How to save Pdf file generated by ignited/laravel-pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-4, wkhtmltopdf

I use the ignited/laravel-pdf pacakges to convert the html into file. It convert the html file perfectly.

Unfortunatly, I didn't find a way to store the new file into my system.

I found only one method which are send();

Sample of my code:

```
$html = View::make('welcome', [])->render();
$pdf = PDF::make();
$pdf->addPage($html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library is using the `mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf`library. If you have a look at the source code, there's a method called `saveAs()` which sounds like what you're searching for. Have a look here: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf/blob/master/src/Pdf.php#L146

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->send ('filename.pdf');
```